# Guice , afterPropertiesSet

Tags: java, guice

Someone knows some way that how can I achieve the same functionality in Guice as the '[afterPropertiesSet](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html)' interface in spring ? 
( its a post construction hook )

Comment: The interface you're referring to is `InitializingBean`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it is not yet supported , so for everyone how wants this work , here is small solution.

```
public class PostConstructListener implements TypeListener{

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(PostConstructListener.class);

    @Override
    public <I> void hear(TypeLiteral<I> iTypeLiteral,final TypeEncounter<I> iTypeEncounter) {

        Class<? super I> type = iTypeLiteral.getRawType();

        ReflectionUtils.MethodFilter mf = new ReflectionUtils.MethodFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean matches(Method method) {
                return method.isAnnotationPresent(PostConstruct.class);
            }
        };

        ReflectionUtils.MethodCallback mc = new ReflectionUtils.MethodCallback() {
            @Override
            public void doWith(Method method) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
                if (!(method.getReturnType().equals(Void.TYPE) && method.getParameterTypes().length == 0))
                {
                    logger.warn("Only VOID methods having 0 parameters are supported by the PostConstruct annotation!" +
                            "method " + method.getName() + " skipped!");
                    return;

                }
                iTypeEncounter.register(new PostConstructInvoker<I>(method));
            }
        };

        ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(type,mc,mf);
    }

    class PostConstructInvoker<I> implements InjectionListener<I>{

        private Method method;

        public PostConstructInvoker(Method method) {
            this.method = method;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterInjection(I o) {
            try {
                method.invoke(o);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The [ReflectionUtils](http://apollo89.com/java/spring-framework-2.5.3/api/org/springframework/util/ReflectionUtils.html) package is defined in spring.

Bind this listener to any event with :

```
bindListener(Matchers.any(),new PostConstructListener());
```

in your guice module. Have fun

Answer (score 8):

By far the simplest solution, if you're using constructor injection and not doing anything too crazy, is to create a post-construction method and annotate it with `@Inject`:

```
final class FooImpl implements Foo {
  private final Bar bar;

  @Inject
  FooImpl(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;

    ...
  }

  @Inject
  void init() {
    // Post-construction code goes here!
  }
}
```

When Guice provides FooImpl, it'll see it has an `@Inject` constructor, call it, and then search for methods annotated with `@Inject` and call those. The intended use case for this is setter injection, but even if an `@Inject` method has no params, Guice will call it.

I don't recommend using this if you're using setter or field injection to inject deps since I don't know if Guice makes any guarantees about the order in which `@Inject` methods are called (that is, your `init()` method might not be guaranteed to be called last). That said, constructor injection is the preferred approach anyway, so that should be a non-issue.

Answer (score 5):

I guess using @PostConstruct is the way to go.

Here is a related blog post : http://macstrac.blogspot.com/2008/10/adding-support-for-postconstruct.html

And here is an addon library that provides the support : http://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit/

Adding lifecycle support via Guiceyfruit is described here : http://code.google.com/p/guiceyfruit/wiki/Lifecycle

Comment: `@PostConstruct` is the preferred approach in Spring, also

Comment: I just dont understand , do I have to download some patch to add support for this JRS annotations ?

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to read the [CustomInjections](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomInjections) page on the Guice wiki:

> In addition to the standard `@Inject`-driven injections, Guice includes hooks for custom injections. This enables Guice to host other frameworks that have their own injection semantics or annotations. Most developers won't use custom injections directly; but they may see their use in extensions and third-party libraries. Each custom injection requires a type listener, an injection listener, and registration of each.