# how to do unit test for Singleton pattern using jmockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, design-patterns, singleton, jmockit

There is a java class, it is based on Singleton pattern. how to do unit test for this class? the following is my related code:

```
public class ConfigFromFile implements ConfigStrategy {
  private String endpoint;
  private final static String CONFIG_FILE = "/conf/config.properties";

  private InputStream getInputStream(String configFilePath) throws FileNotFoundException{
    return new FileInputStream(configFilePath);
  }

  private void initFromFile() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    try {
      input = getInputStream(CONFIG_FILE);
      prop.load(input);
      endpoint = prop.getProperty("endpoint");
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      if (input != null) {
        try {
          input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private ConfigFromFile() {
    initFromFile();
  }

  private static class ConfigFromFileHolder {
    private static ConfigFromFile instance = new ConfigFromFile();
  }

  public static ConfigFromFile getInstance() {
    return ConfigFromFileHolder.instance;
  }

  @Override
  public String getEndpoint() {
      return endpoint;
  }
}
```

I need to write unit test for this class.

- the unit test can't call the external resource, so we need to mock call "/conf/config.properties" file. we can use jmockit.
- this class is based on Singleton pattern. We hope that the interaction between the two cases can not be affected.

The following is my case:

1. Case1, it is normal case, the file content is "endpoint=www.baidu.com"
2. Case2, it is an abnormal case, we can mock this file does not exist.

how to implement these cases? Thanks!

Comment: @namshubwriter you missed the Singleton error in your edit.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I generally only improve formatting when I edit questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a **package-scope constructor that takes in the path of the file to load**, and have your test create a fake file in a temporary folder, and then create an instance of your test, passing in the path to the file. No mocking necessary.

```
public class ConfigFromFile implements ConfigStrategy {
  private static final String CONFIG_FILE = "/conf/config.properties";
  private final String configFilePath;
  private String endpoint;

  // Visible for testing
  ConfigStrategy(String configFilePath) {
    this.configFilePath = configFilePath;
  }

  private ConfigStrategy() {
    this(CONFIG_FILE);
  }

  private void initFromFile() {
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(configFilePath)) {
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      prop.load(input);
      endpoint = prop.getProperty("endpoint");
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  ...

}
```

Note I rewrote `initFromFile()` to **use try-with-resources**, which you can do if if you are using JDK 7 or above.

You might want to reconsider whether this class needs to be a static singleton. It not only makes the code harder to test, but it can't be configured to use different files in different environments. Remember that **the test for a class is the class's first user of the API**. If your test is hard to write, that can indicate problems with your API.

If you need to restrict to one instance, I suggest **using a dependency injection framework** like Guice or Spring. If you use Spring, your class can implement `InitializingBean` and load the configuration file after the class is constructed but before it is injected into another class:

```
public class ConfigFromFile implements ConfigStrategy, InitializingBean {
  private final String configFilePath;
  private String endpoint;

  ConfigStrategy(String configFilePath) {
    this.configFilePath = configFilePath;
  }

  @Override
  public void afterPropertiesSet() throws IOException {
    try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(configFilePath)) {
      Properties prop = new Properties();
      prop.load(input);
      endpoint = prop.getProperty("endpoint");
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String getEndpoint() {
    return endpoint;
  }
}
```

Yes, that's all the code you need.

- no need to catch the exception
- an exception loading the config file won't be silently ignored
- no need to have `getEndpoint()` check if the initialization failed

You can do [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2912278/95725) with Guice.

But wait, if you use Spring, and you are willing to move the endpoint value into the Spring configuration, then it gets even simpler!

```
public class ConfigFromSpring implements ConfigStrategy {
  private final String endpoint;

  ConfigStrategy(String endpoint) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
  }

  @Override
  public String getEndpoint() {
    return endpoint;
  }
}
```

The class is so simple, it doesn't need any unit tests.

Your bean XML would look like this:

```
<bean id="config" class="examples.ConfigFromSpring">
  <constructor-arg type="String" value="end of the road"/>
</bean>
```

Of course, at this point I would get rid of `ConfigStrategy` and set the configuration on the object that uses the configuration.